# Video errors across apps

Tags: video-recording, video-streaming

I have an annoying problem. My Huawei honor 4c began some time ago to refuse to play videos on many different apps. I first noticed the problem on YouTube (I get the common "tap to try again" error, but the app immediately freezes). Then I realized I can't play videos on Google Photos or Facebook either. Peculiarly, I noticed I can't even record videos with the camera app.
All errors (that is, in all affected apps) are resolved with a reboot, but at some point (apparently random?) they appear again.
I haven't installed any new app or anything of the sort. 
Any ideas?
The Android version is 4.2.2

Comment: I was going to say "Try switching players in dev settings" but can't remembe if it is on JB.

Comment: Can you clarify a bit - so that i could at least know where to look to see if it's in 4.2.2? Is "dev[ice] settings" a subgroup of "settings"? If so, then I can't see it anywhere

Comment: No, Its Development settings (where you can enable ADB and other stuff) it shows on the main settings menu AFTER you've tapped the build number in about phone 7-8 times

Comment: Found the Dev Settings, but no option to switch players. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: No problem. Huuhhhhh, tries factory reset? It can help. Back up yur stuff first, of course.